# How do I write/read to/from disk Spray json object?

Tags: scala, serialization, spray-json

I want to be able to read/write Json object from/to disk.

I admit, in Java it would have been taking me about 10 minutes.

Scala is a bit more challenging. I think that the main reason is not enough info on the net.

Anyway, this is what I have done so far:

```js
package com.example

import java.io.{BufferedWriter, FileWriter}

import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

object Test {

  object Foo extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo.apply)
  }

  case class Foo(name: String, x: String) {
    //def toJson:JsValue = JsObject( "name" -> JsString(name) )
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")

    implicit val foo = new Foo("xxx", "jj")

    println(foo.toJson)

    val w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))
    w.write(x.toJson) // This doesn't work. I also tried: x.toJson.toString
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What's the `x` in the last line? are you trying to `write` or `read` the JSON ?

Comment: Sorry Soumya, the meaning was: foo.toJson. Anyway, this worked: x.toJson.toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aw, that's disappointing.  I contributed a diagram to the [spray-json readme](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) that I hoped would be helpful to newcomers.  But you still have to figure out what to do about the implicits.

Spray-json uses typeclasses to serialize/deserialize objects.  You might want to read up on typeclasses, but the important thing to know here is that implicit JsonFormat objects have to be in scope for all of the classes used by the object and the things it references.  The DefaultJsonProtocol trait contains implicit JsonFormats for common Scala types, and you must provide your own implicit JsonFormats for your own types.  The jsonFormat1,2,... methods provide an easy way to create such JsonFormats for case classes.

There are a number of problems with your program.  Here's a simple one that works:

```
import spray.json._
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, FileWriter}

object Test extends App with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  case class Foo(name: String, x: String)
  implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo.apply)
  val foo = Foo("xxx", "jj")
  println(foo.toJson)
  val w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))
  w.write(foo.toJson.prettyPrint)
  w.close
}
```

Comment: Thanks AmigoNico. The "readme" looks GREAT. I just didn't see it. It's kinda getting lost with all the files... :)

Comment: Glad that helped, bashan.  Good luck.

Comment: I am skeptical as to why wasn't file IO considered as a basic requirement in spray-json and we have to resort to BufferedWriter? Moreover your code does not compile.

Comment: @Arunav: Rather than having a JSON serialization/deserialization library, a complex math library, a signal conditioning library, and a hundred others each do file I/O in case you want to store a result to a file, each with it's own API, wouldn't it be better to let each have a Single Responsibility and use your own small method for dumping a String to a file?

Comment: @Arunav: Regarding the (unfriendly?) "Moreover your code does not compile" comment, I just re-checked it; it builds/runs just fine for me with Scala 2.12.0 and spray-json 1.3.2. If you would like help, why not create a new question referencing this one and providing info that people would need in order to help you?