# Fastest way to convert nested String to JSON

Tags: json, scala

I have a large text file, each line of this file is a nested String, which similar with this:

```
{"data":"test","field":"test","listObj":[{"data":"testInner1","field":"testInner1"},{"data":"testInner2","field":"testInner2"}],"obj":{"data":"testInner1","field":"testInner1"}}
```

You can see the above String actually has the following structure, but stored as a single line and not readable:

```
{ 
  "data" : "test", 
  "field" : "test", 
  "listObj" : [{ 
      "data" : "testInner1", 
      "field" : "testInner1" 
   } , { 
      "data" : "testInner2", 
      "field" : "testInner2"
   }],
   "obj" : { 
      "data" : "testInner1", 
      "field" : "testInner1" 
   }
}
```

I would like to convert each line of the text file to JSON object in Scala, and I can't design a mapper pattern for this file because each line could have different structure.

In this case I used JSON library from Play framework to create the following simple code:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
        for(line <- Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines()) {
            val lineStr = line.mkString
            val jsonString = Json.toJson(lineStr)
            val readableString: String = Json.prettyPrint(jsonString)
            println(readableString)
        }
    }
```

But the output of "readableString" is like this:

```
"{\"data\":\"test\",\"field\":\"test\",\"listObj\":[{\"data\":\"testInner1\",\"field\":\"testInner1\"},{\"data\":\"testInner2\",\"field\":\"testInner2\"}],\"obj\":{\"data\":\"testInner1\",\"field\":\"testInner1\"}}"
```

Here are my questions:

1. The above output is not what I want, I expected a JSON
   object with readable structure. Is there has a way to achieve that?
2. Besides of convert the nested String to JSON, what is the fastest
   way to convert a very large text file to JSON objects? Which library
   should I to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question 1 - duplicate. Question 2 - "recommend library" - off-topic.

Comment: It's true that the other question deals with how to pretty-print JSON in Play.  As for the performance of various JSON parsers, Jackson-based parsers are probably the best if performance is all that matters.  But the latest version of Spray-json is within spitting distance of Jackson's performance and has other advantages.

Comment: @AmigoNico Thanks a lot for the recommendation! I will try both Jackson and Spray.

Comment: This may be helpful in getting started with Spray-json: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206068/how-do-i-write-read-to-from-disk-spray-json-object/27210225#27210225